# Tests Getting Stuck While Using @SpringBootTest

Tags: java, spring

I have the following code in my Test class.

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = {Application.class, TestConfig.class})
```

I have the above line in my tests file. I have a method in a `@Component` class that listens to a `Kafka` topic in an infinite loopand  is triggered by `@EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)`.

Now, not only are the tests not run, the beans defined in my `TestConfig.class` are not created as well. Can someone explain to me why this is happening? If I start my infinite loop in a different thread, this problem is mitigated.